# How do you remove a self-installed DLL?

Tags: dll

I have a DLL on a server that has somehow been registered as self installed instead of a Component Service it is under Microsoft/COM3/SelfReg/CLSID with the ID and information for this DLL stored there - this component needs to be replaced or removed for updating how do you remove it regsvr32 will not work and there is no visible entry for it other than in the registry. How to Unregister this is all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons people claim self-registration is evil is that there is no guarantee that rollback will work.  If regsvr32 refuses to unregister it and there's nothing in add/remove programs (which there could be if someone manually added the registry entries as part of a component), then deleting the registry entries manually may be the best you can do.  Some people who make dlls just make the assumption that once installed, they should never be deleted.